# Книги по графике на C++

Tags: графика, книги, c++

А как вы научились создавать графику на C++? Какие книги посоветуете новичку?

Comment: Если хочешь создать игру, то лучше использовать готовый движок, а не писать его самому. Но знания по C++ нужны будут для написании сценария.

Comment: @Исмаил, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне очень сильно помогла книга Игоря Тарасова [Основы OpenGL](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/opengl/)

Answer (score 1):

Самая полезная из книг по графике, которые я читал - это "OpenGL суперкнига". Там всё очень подробно объясняется. Если нужно узнать что-то новое, чего нет в ней, я ищу на steps3d.narod.ru. У Борескова очень много разных статей по графике (правда в них много ошибок).